# Loading native code in an OSGi bundle via more specific processor architecture filters

Tags: osgi, native

When a native library is registered in an OSGi bundle, you use the `Bundle-NativeCode` header:

```
libjnotify.so;osname = Linux;processor = x86
```

This makes the `libjnotify.so` library available if the Java VM is executing in a x86 Linux environment.

[The possible processor architectures are listed on the OSGi website](http://www.osgi.org/Specifications/Reference). However, this doesn't cover new OSs or processor architectures. Furthermore, it doesn't cover environments for which simply the processor architecture is not enough.

For an example of the latter case, consider ARM environments. OSGi offers us ARM_le and ARM_be but my understanding is that this is not enough. Different versions of the ARM architecture (ARMv6, ARMv7 etc.), regardless of endianness, are not binary-compatible. Furthermore, ARM architectures with an FPU can be running an OS that uses either the 'soft float' (armel) or 'hard float' (armhf) ABI. Libraries compiled for hard float cannot be run on soft float systems, and vice versa.

So in these more complex environments, how should native code be loaded?

Answer (score 4):

You can set system properties when you launch Java to define the os name and processor:

`-Dorg.osgi.framework.processor=my_processor_name -Dorg.osgi.framework.os.name=my_os_name`

See section 4.5.3 in the Core R5 spec.

You can then reference those names in your Bundle-NativeCode header.

Also, you can submit new OS and processor names to OSGi as outlined on http://www.osgi.org/Specifications/Reference.

Comment: The startup flag is very useful, thanks.  With regard to submission of OS and processor names, the OSGi instructions are to run their `properties.jar` and report the output.  Unfortunately on my test system (ARMv7, le, hf) running Ubuntu 12.04, the architecture is simply reported as 'arm'.  I think this issue may go further than OSGi, because `System.getProperties("os.arch");` returns the same thing.

Comment: Well it means your JVM vendor does not set the ```os.arch``` property to a descriptive enough value. So setting the OSGi properties as I described is your workaround.

Comment: Indeed.  For info, the JVM is OpenJDK 7 (7u21-2.3.9-0ubuntu0.12.04.1).  I'll try it with the Oracle Java8/JavaFX hard-float ARM preview version when I have a chance.

Comment: There is a bug in Felix that makes this not work. Felix always sets the OSGi configuration properties like org.osgi.framework.os.name to its default. The escape is to create a filter. (See bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-5875?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=16527524#comment-16527524)